# Update site automatically by calling a function

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, web

I am building a news website using ASP.NET. I want it to be updated automatically by pulling new news articles. This is done by calling a function which downloads the updated json string.

How do i call this function every half hour in C#?
Or should i write this function in javascript and call that every half hour?

Comment: You can generate cron job for the same.

Comment: you can take a look at `SignalR` (http://www.asp.net/signalr)

Answer (score 2):

You can use Timer in C#

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // Create a timer
        System.Timers.Timer myTimer = new System.Timers.Timer();

        //call method
        myTimer.Elapsed += new ElapsedEventHandler(mymethod);

        //time interval 5 sec
        myTimer.Interval = 5000;
        myTimer.Enabled = true;
    }

public void mymethod(object source, ElapsedEventArgs e)
    {            
        //your code
    }
```

Also, you can use SetTimeOut function in Javascript

```
setTimeout(function() {  

//calls click event after a certain time
    that.element.click();
}, 5000);
```

OR

Use Task for this

```
Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
    {
        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(5000);
        CallMethod();
    });
```

Comment: Will this work even when the website is not open?
Will it call the function in the background?
I am hosting the site at GoDaddy.

Comment: what do you mean by Website is not open? & from where you are pulling news? from another website or from database?

Comment: Use Timer instead of thread.

Comment: I am pulling from a database. So every half hour i need to download a json string and update the database accordingly. Using a timer, will it download the string and update the database automatically in the background?

Comment: Yes. Replace mymethod in my code with your method.

Answer (score 1):

Use below in head tag to refresh your page,

```
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="value">
```

Here value is in seconds. If you want to refresh page after 30 mins use 1800 as a value.

Answer (score 1):

1. You can set your website's data source to somewhere like Json/XML
   static file or a DB.
2. Create a scheduler which will look for new data in your specific
   interval at your specific place where you are getting your Json
   string.
3. Your scheduler will update your data source which will update your news

Answer (score 0):

By definition websites don’ t have time triggers. Each request is independent and the server can be in “sleep” mode before requests.

But the problem you describe is pretty common.

There are few methods to solve it :

1. Hacky method: having a page opened and some javascript making a call every XX minutes/seconds
2. If you use Microsoft Azure, you can use Web Jobs future (free) or Scheduler function (free for 5 operations)
3. You can develop a Windows Service witch will call your site every XX minuts. Exelent framework (free) is Quartz. You’ll need to host this service on “always on” windows PC, separated from your web site

Comment: If i use javascript to call my function in C#, will it call the function even when the website is not open? In the background?
So when i open the website(let's say after 30 minutes), i will view the updates content?

Answer (score 0):

You should create a windows service for this. because it will run in background even after your website page is not opened.

Else

Use Microsoft Azure , it will help you to create your scheduler function that will keep continue to update your website content.